# Find which points in one table are in which polygons in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spatial-query

I have a table t which are my points

```
create table t ( 
  PointID bigint 
 ,lat varchar(9)
 ,long varchar(9)
 ,geom geometry 
 ,PolygonID bigint 
);
```

And I have table p which are my polygons

```
create table p ( 
 PolygonID bigint 
 ,geom geometry 
);
```

Now I need something like

```
;with polygon_cte as p 
(select geom from p) 

UPDATE t 
SET t.PolygonID = p.PolygonID 
WHERE p.geom.STContains(t.geom)
```

I'm sure my points and polygons have converted right, and I know I'll need to add a spatial index once I have this down but I'm having trouble figuring out how to update t my points table with the right PolygonID from my polygon table.  There will be only one polygon for each point as the polygons are mutually exclusive in terms of geographic area.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE p SET PolygonID=(SELECT PolygonID FROM t WHERE t.geom.STContains(p.geom)=1)
```

If there are multiple polygons for the same point, you will get a "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error.